# Put 4 boxes in a box - How to

Tags: logical-deduction

John has divided a box in two. John wants to put two boxes in each part of the box. Can he do it? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What is the size of the boxes? Are they all the same?

Comment: You can put in each part of the box 1 object.

Comment: This question does not appear to be a puzzle - or if it is, it's very under-defined. In any case, it's certainly not a [logic-puzzle].) Please edit your question with clarification on what the "rules" of the puzzle are.

Comment: This reminds of [that one magic trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jLgBIplUTs).

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> Yes he can.

Explanation:

> The boxes can be smaller, therefore fitting two in each half.